# Python-saving while loop results

Tags: python

hello i am trying to save the printed results from this while loop and then upload them to a database

```
i=0
x=0
n=0

while x < len(round1):
    n +=1
    print 'match number',n, ':' ,round1[x],scoretop[i],'VS','team:', round1[x+1],scorebottom[i],"\n"
    x=x+2
    i=i+1
```

i am totally new to python so sorry if this is an easy question

Comment: *sorry if this is an easy question* - what is the question? What do you mean by *upload them to a database*? etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a data structure beforehand and append to it while you are in the loop:

```
results = [] # A list of the results that 
             # that we will get in the while loop
i=0
x=0
n=0

while x < len(round1):
    n +=1
    results.append(' '.join(map(str,
                                ['match number',
                                n,
                                ':' ,
                                round1[x],
                                scoretop[i],
                                'VS','team:',
                                round1[x+1],scorebottom[i],"\n"])))
    x=x+2
    i=i+1
```

The results will then be saved in the `results` list, which you can then loop over and send to the database:

```
for i in results:
    send_to_database(i)
```

Or you can concatenate all the strings together and send them that way if you like:

```
send_to_database('\n'.join(results))
```

Comment: thank you for the quick reply i tried what you suggested but i get this error " round1[x+1],scorebottom[i],"\n")))
TypeError: argument 3 to map() must support iteration" what am i missing ?

Comment: @user3083018 My bad, should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on some UNIX-like system you can run this and redirect the output to a file like this:

```
python your-file.py > output.txt
```

Then you can manually upload the output to your database.

If you want to upload the results automatically you should safe the results in a list, instead of printing them, and then upload them through the API of your database. Look at dg123's answer for details on saving you results in a list.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to `print` to file, you can simply write to a file:

```
with open('log.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    while x < len(round1):
    # some operations
    out = ' '.join(map(str, ['match number', n, ':', round1[x], scoretop[i], 'VS', 'team:',  round1[x+1], scorebottom[i], "\n"]))
    outfile.write(out)
```

If you are working on UNIX machines, just follow the suggestion of @Ich Und Nicht Du